# Create a form on an ASPX page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am trying to create a form with a post on my aspx page in my asp.net application.

```
<form method="POST" action="https://www.vcs.co.za/vvonline/vcs.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" id="vcsTerminalId" name="p1" value="a" runat="server"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="vcsReference" name="p2" value="b" runat="server"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="vcsDescription" name="p3" value="c" runat="server"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="vcsAmount" name="p4" value="d" runat="server"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="vcsHash" name="hash" value="q" runat="server"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Proceed to payment" />
</form>
```

How ever during run time this form disapears and the submit but is used for the page form. During run time my whole page is placed into a form. I think this is a asp thing.

When working on my page it will looks something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/template/site.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContainer" Runat="Server">
//Content inside!!!!!
</asp:Content>
```

During run time:

```
<form method="post" action="SearchResult.aspx?id=1561901" id="form1">
//Content in side
</form>
```

How can i add and is that top mentioned Form?

Comment: any thing you would write in "mainContainer" will be placed inside the body of the master page.

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui Yes that's where i display my page, on this page i want a button to do a post. So i need it in a Form. But everything in Main Container is placed in a form already, and you can't nest forms as far as i know, so it removes my form and just has the sumbit button.

Comment: i am not getting your problem its very simple. just drag a button from toolbox. inside the main container and you can use the button to post the form.

Comment: moreover you have to bind the button click event to post the form on button click

Comment: moreover you input field are hidden . this can also be the reason you are only seeing button.

Comment: The wonders of `WebForms`.

Comment: You have a `form` already there. Any other `form` you try to add will be nested, which is invalid. Or you get rid of the main `form` or use it. You decide.

Comment: Since i can't add a new form inside a form, and i can't add an action to a contentPlaceHolder, is there a way to recreate the post method in a redirect? How does a form submit handle its parameters?

Something like:

 Response.Redirect("https://www.vcs.co.za/vvonline/vcs.aspx?" + "p1=005S&p2=" + Reference + "&p3=" + Description + "&p4=" + Amount + "&hash=" + hash);

Comment: @Pomster, see my answer for how you can recreate it from CodeBehind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing cross-page posts has always been a bit awkward with WebForms.

To keep my markup clean from hacks, I've been using a helper class to do it from CodeBehind:

```
RemotePost remotePostHelper = new RemotePost("https://www.vcs.co.za/vvonline/vcs.aspx");
remotePostHelper.Add("p1", "a");
remotePostHelper.Add("p2", "b");
remotePostHelper.Add("p3", "c");
remotePostHelper.Post();
```

Helper class:

```
public partial class RemotePost
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the remote URL to POST to.
    /// </summary>
    public string PostUrl
    { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the form's HTML name.
    /// </summary>
    public string FormName
    { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the collection of POST data.
    /// </summary>
    public NameValueCollection PostData
    { get; private set; }


    /// <param name="postUrl">The remote URL to POST to.</param>
    public RemotePost(string postUrl)
    {
        this.PostData = new NameValueCollection();
        this.PostUrl = postUrl;
        this.FormName = "formName";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified name and value to the POST data collection..
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the element to add</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the element to add.</param>
    public void Add(string name, string value)
    {
        this.PostData.Add(name, value);
    }

    public void Post()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Write("<html><head>");
        context.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", this.FormName));
        context.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"post\" action=\"{1}\" >", this.FormName, this.PostUrl));

        foreach(string name in this.PostData)
        {
            context.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(this.PostData[name])));
        }

        context.Response.Write("</form>");
        context.Response.Write("</body></html>");
        context.Response.End();
    }
}
```